# T-Mobile Sidekick 4G Keyboard - Tilde and Backtick

Tags: keyboard, t-mobile-sidekick-4g

I still have a G1. I love it for its keyboard. Nobody, has made a phone with a better keyboard. It has 5 rows and allows me to type the full ASCII range and then some. The keys are spaced apart and not easily fat-fingered like the Verizon Droid line of phones. I have been holding out on getting a new phone, waiting for one with a keyboard as good or even better. I had hope in the Sidekick, but upon closer inspection of the keyboard, it does not appear to have a back-tick <kbd>`</kbd> or tilde <kbd>~</kbd> key. Where the back-tick should be, I see a smiley face.

On Sidekick 4G keyboard, what is the fastest way for me to type a tilde and a back-tick? The person with the least amount of actions to accomplish this goal gets my vote.

[image: Sidekick 4g Kbd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much torment and due to an unfortunate accident, I went ahead and purchased one. The answer is:

#### Tilde

1. Close screen
2. Tap the input area
3. long press a
4. click tilde

#### Backtick (grave)

1. Close screen
2. Tap the input area
3. long press apostrophe
4. realize that you were pressing the voice search button since the apostrophe button is so small and cramped, so cancel the voice search
5. repeat 3 until success
6. click backtick

This is a major pain. I may just make an alternate soft keyboard for myself that just has those two buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don' think they characters can be typed with the sidekick hardware keyboard. As for the software keyboard, it would depend on the one you are using, but most likely would be close to this:

- Switch to numbers / symbols
- press the alt key
- press the  <kbd>`</kbd>  or  <kbd>~</kbd>  key

Comment: It does not **have** to be reliant on the hardware keyboard. I just want to know the fastest way to do so.

Comment: no dice. and by dice, I mean <kbd>alt</kbd> key. Samsung and their stupid wipe keyboard has decided to invent new nomenclature and call this the <kbd>sym</kbd> button, and it still does not seem useful, i.e. no <kbd>`</kbd>.

Comment: I use the stock keyboard. well, not even the stock samsung keyboard, i use the real "stock keyboard". There is a pretty good keyboard called hackers keyboard that has every key you can think of on it.